# Check / uncheck all component checkboxes in Inno Setup

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup

I have long list of components which in turn calls a sub setup file to installs the selected components.
All the components comes with check box which user can select and deselect.
I need a check box at the top clicking which will Check/Uncheck all in the component list.

Can this be done ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a top-level master component:

```
[Components]
Name: "all"; Description: "All"; Types: full compact custom;
Name: "all\comp1"; Description: "Component 1"; Types: full compact custom;
Name: "all\comp2"; Description: "Component 2"; Types: full compact custom;
Name: "all\comp3"; Description: "Component 3"; Types: full compact custom;
```

[image]